# Load only the data I need on page change fo ngTable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I want to display a list of objects on a table. The number of records in my database though could be a few thousand items, and I would like to only dynamically query for the items that are needed for the page I am.

The way I query for the data is by using something like

```
myfactory.Query = function(querystring) {
  var getdata = {
    'operation': 'query',
    'query': querystring
  };
  return $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: myscripturl,
    params: getdata
  });
};
```

and I can actually type a simple query from my javascript file like such

```
myFactory.Query("Select * from files limit 0,100");
```

or

```
myFactory.Query("Select count(*) from files");
```

In my controller I am trying something like this:

```
$scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
        page: 1,
        count: 100
    }, {
        total: 1000, // Randomly puting this here.
        getData: function($defer, params) {
                var limit1 = params.page();
                var limit2 = params.page() + params.count();
                return myFactory.Query('SELECT * FROM testTable LIMIT ' + limit1 + ',' + limit2).then(function(response) {
                    return response.data.result
                });
            }
    });
```

I am not sure how to achieve what I described using ngTables though, so I would hopefully like an example on how and if this can be done. 
Mainly I am having trouble to set total count, since I only return lets say 10 records on each page change. But the total could be as I said a few thousand records.

Comment: Can we see your html and controller code?

Comment: @jbrown I updated my code including the table parameters code, hopefully giving a better idea of what I am trying to do.

Comment: I'm no expert for ngTable but I would try this for starters.  Let the page settings remain as default {} and assign data to a variable (data) after getData() promise is resolved.  It would look like this: $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, { dataset: data});  Then when you see your data is rendering you can work on paging.

Comment: Thats not exactly my issue, what my problem is with the default implementation, is that its too slow for when I have a lot of records. How for example do I deal with a table of thousands of records when just getting all the data from the server is impractical or very slow.